# Using Jena with Pellet; NoClassDefFoundError Exception

Tags: java, jena, pellet

I'm trying to use Jena 2.12.1 with Pellet; I downloaded the latest Apache Jena library from their site [Jena 2.12.1](http://mirror.symnds.com/software/Apache/jena/binaries/apache-jena-2.12.1.zip).

First, I downloaded [Pellet 2.3.1](http://clarkparsia.com/pellet/download/pellet-2.3.1) and imported the JENA libraries. Unfortunately, `org.mindswap.pellet.jena.PelletReasonerFactory` couldn't be resolved, and thus, I couldn't instantiate a reasoner.

Then, I downloaded multiple versions the jar file pellet-jena-2.3.2 (tried 2.3.1 and 2.3.0). This resolved `org.mindswap.pellet.jena.PelletReasonerFactory`. However it caused the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mindswap/pellet/utils/progress/ProgressMonitor
at org.mindswap.pellet.jena.PelletReasoner.bind(PelletReasoner.java:95)
at org.mindswap.pellet.jena.PelletReasoner.bind(PelletReasoner.java:53)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory.createInfModel(ModelFactory.java:261)
at code.BasicOWLHandler.main(BasicOWLHandler.java:678)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mindswap.pellet.utils.progress.ProgressMonitor


at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 4 more
```

My code:

```
import org.mindswap.pellet.jena.PelletReasonerFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.InfModel;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.reasoner.Reasoner;

public class Test {
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    Reasoner reasoner = PelletReasonerFactory.theInstance().create();

    // create an empty model
    Model emptyModel = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel( );

    // create an inferencing model using Pellet reasoner
    InfModel model = ModelFactory.createInfModel( reasoner, emptyModel );
}   
}
```

**What is the problem? is there a better way to use jena 2.12.1 with Pellet (any version)?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using pellet-2.3.0 (Aug 22, 2011) including JENA compatible librairies instead of pellet-2.3.1 has solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says it can't find `org.mindswap.pellet.utils.progress.ProgressMonitor` when called from `org.mindswap.pellet.jena.PelletReasoner.bind`. That looks like the classpath does not have all the necessary Pellet jars.  It is nothing to do with Jena.

However, see http://clarkparsia.com/pellet/faq/different-jena-version/.
Pellet is unlikely to work perfectly with Jena 2.12.1 due to the 2+ year gap.

You may wish to try this fork or one of its branches: https://github.com/ansell/pellet (no recommendation either way)

The link you give to Jena is not the master site - it looks like a mirror of  http://www.apache.org/dist/jena.

Comment: I checked the first link you provided; They say that each Pellet distribution contains a compatible JENA version. I downloaded and included the [Pellet 2.3.1] (http://clarkparsia.com/pellet/download/pellet-2.3.1) which also includes JENA 2.10; However I still have an unresolved import `org.mindswap.pellet.jena.PelletReasonerFactory`. This import can be resolved in pellet-jena jar file which I wonder why isn't it inclued in the Pellet distribution; so I had to import it from an external link and this causes the mentioned exception. However, I think this isn't the best way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If anybody comes across this and wants to use Jena **2.13** together with Pellet, it's possible since *July 14, 2015* using Pellet **2.4**. See commit [#7b07bf](https://github.com/Complexible/pellet/commit/7b07bf1962b98922cd018a323da364119f0b8394).

Get get it up and running you just have to build the JARs yourself by cloning their repo and running `mvn compile`. They also include [an example](https://github.com/Complexible/pellet/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/mindswap/pellet/examples/SPARQLDLExample.java) using Jena 2.13.

To use Pellet with Jena simple follow the instruction on [their FAQs](https://github.com/Complexible/pellet/wiki/FAQ#how-can-i-use-pellet-with-jena):

```java
// ontology that will be used
String ont = "http://www.mindswap.org/2004/owl/mindswappers";

// create an empty ontology model using Pellet spec
OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( PelletReasonerFactory.THE_SPEC );   

// read the file
model.read( ont );
```